# Huge puddle of water under car

Tags: ac, dodge, leak, viper

I parked my Dodge Viper after driving for about two hours (in July, ~90°F, AC at full blast). Half an hour later I noticed a huge puddle under the engine, on the passenger side.

I am pretty sure it was water since it was thin, odorless, and cool. I'm guessing it was sweat from running the AC but I have never seen it do this before and the puddle was massive - about a yard squared. Is this normal or could there be a leak?

Comment: Viper's have A/C units? Who'da thunk it :P

Comment: @Paulster2 you can't tell when you're in one. It's a constant battle, AC vs. V10 engine heat (the cats specifically), and the AC always loses.

Comment: Does a Viper reeeally need cats? I mean, legality aside, it's already a V10, how much more harm could it do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most likely cause is the a/c unit. What may have happened is that debris, pine needles,leaves etc may have plugged the drain allowing an excess amount of water to build up and then it relaesed. Run the a/c unit for awhile say 30 minutes. In a safe area like an empty parking lot make some abrubt turns at slow speeds. If you hear water sloshing under the passenger side dash the drain is clogged. If you look under the hood on the passenger side you may see a rubber "L" shaped hose. You might be able to clean it out with a small piece of wire.

Comment: Right - it's not "sweat" from the AC.  It's much more likely a bunch of water from the dehumidifying side of the AC.  A hot humid day is going to require the AC to remove a lot of water from the air before it will cool effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its normal. Saw this bundle of water under the car. Frightened me initially. Its water due to condensation. Its nothing to worry.